# Excel import in access using winforms .NET4 confusing me

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, excel-interop

I have situation which I am unable to solve and need some suggestion.

I have excel spreadsheet. Like below which has Heading, Sub Heading and Data.

How I import this. Like

**How I know when importing data that which row/value is heading/sub heading/data. ?**

**Note:** data is in groups.

[image]

Comment: what do you get if you try to import this sheet as if it was a normal flat table? can you show us your code and tell what is happening unexpected?

Comment: @davide-piras , There is no error and I get the data from excel. But if you read my question. I can not find the way to know which is heading/subheading/data when reading from excel.

Answer (score 0):

The first column of you spreadsheet contains a number(group number?),you can use it!

Comment: How? . Can you show me a line of code to use it as a group? and what about subheading?

Comment: traverse you rows,find the first cell of current row.the value decide the current row delong to which group.and the first appear row  should be your heading,others are data or subheading, i found you data and sub heading not have obvious different.you must find the difference